# I want to check output from print statement using pytest capsys but I am getting error like 'TestCoffeeMachine' object has no attribute 'capsys'

Tags: python, fixtures

```
import pytest
import unittest

from CoffeeMachine import CoffeeMachine
```

```
class TestCoffeeMachine(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.coffee_1 = CoffeeMachine(200, 300, 20, 0)
```

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def _pass_fixtures(self, capsys):
    self.capfd = capsys
```

```
def test_cost_calculation(self):
    return_value = self.coffee_1.cost_calculation(CoffeeMachine.coffee_type[0], 10.50)
    captured = self.capsys.readouterr()
    self.assertEqual("Total Money Loaded is: 10.5", captured.out)
    self.assertEqual(return_value[0], True)
    self.assertEqual(return_value[1], 4.95)
```

Error:

```
    captured = self.capsys.readouterr()
AttributeError: 'TestCoffeeMachine' object has no attribute 'capsys'
```

I have tried like passing capsys in method but I am getting error in that also

```
def test_cost_calculation(self, capsys):
    return_value = self.coffee_1.cost_calculation(CoffeeMachine.coffee_type[0], 10.50)
    captured = capsys.readouterr()
    self.assertEqual("Total Money Loaded is: 10.5", captured.out)
    self.assertEqual(return_value[0], True)
    self.assertEqual(return_value[1], 4.95)
```

Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
TypeError: test_cost_calculation() missing 1 required positional argument: 'capsys'

Answer (score 1):

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def capfd(self, capfd):
    self.capfd = capfd
```

Above fixture should be part of your class TestCoffeeMachine, and then your test should look like this:

```
def test_cost_calculation(self):
    return_value = self.coffee_1.cost_calculation(CoffeeMachine.coffee_type[0], 10.50)
    captured = self.capfd.readouterr()
    self.assertEqual("Total Money Loaded is: 10.5", captured.out)
    self.assertEqual(return_value[0], True)
    self.assertEqual(return_value[1], 4.95)
```